# Get a value from one form and use it in another jsp

Tags: javascript, java, forms, jsp

I want to retrieve 2 input field values from one of the 2 forms in my jsp file and use that value in my second form. So I used javascript to get the values from the first form and display it in a hidden input field in the second form so that I could use those values, but it is giving me a number format exception so I'm guessing the values from the first form is not correctly getting passed to the second form. Here is my code:

jsp file:

```
<script>
             function getNumOfDays(){
                 var numOfDays = document.getElementById("numOfDays").value;
                 document.getElementById("hiddenNumDays").value = numOfDays;
             }

             function getTotalMiles(){
                 var totalMiles = document.getElementById("totalMile").value;
                 document.getElementById("hiddenTotalMiles").value = totalMiles;
             }

             function getTotalDue(){
                 var HtotalDue = document.getElementById("totalDue").value;
                 document.getElementById("hiddentTotalDue").value = HtotalDue;
             }
        </script>
```

First Form

```
<form class="form-horizontal" name="selectVehicleForm" action="SelectVehicle">
              <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="col-md-5 control-label">Number of Days Renting:</label>
                    <div class="col-md-3">
                        <input class="form-control" type="text" id="numOfDays" name="numOfDays" disabled>                   
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="col-md-5 control-label">Total Miles:</label>
                    <div class="col-md-3">
                        <input class="form-control" type="text" name="totalMile" id="totalMile" placeholder="approximate">                  
                    </div>
                </div>



                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="col-md-5 control-label">Total Amount Due: $</label>
                    <div class="col-md-3">
                        <input class="form-control" type="text" name="totalDue" id="totalDue" disabled>                  
                    </div>
                </div> 
            </form>
```

Second Form

```
 <input type="text" name="hiddenNumDays" id="hiddenNumDays" disabled>
               <input type="hidden" name="hiddenTotalMiles" id="hiddenTotalMiles" disabled>
               <input type="hidden" name="hiddentTotalDue" id="hiddentTotalDue" disabled>
```

Serlvet:

```
@Override
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException
    {
        Payment paymentInfo = new Payment();
        paymentInfo.setId(10);
        paymentInfo.setFirstName(request.getParameter("firstName"));
        paymentInfo.setLastName(request.getParameter("lastName"));
        paymentInfo.setAddress(request.getParameter("address"));
        paymentInfo.setAptSuit(request.getParameter("aptNum"));
        paymentInfo.setCity(request.getParameter("city"));
        paymentInfo.setState(request.getParameter("state"));
        paymentInfo.setZipcode(request.getParameter("zipCode"));
        paymentInfo.setPhoneNum(request.getParameter("phoneNum"));
        paymentInfo.setEmail(request.getParameter("email"));
        paymentInfo.setCreditCardType(request.getParameter("card"));
        paymentInfo.setCreditCardNum(Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("cardNumber")));
        paymentInfo.setExpirationDate(request.getParameter("expMonth"));
        paymentInfo.setCvCode(Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("cvCode")));
        paymentInfo.setNumOfDays(Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("hiddenNumDays")));
        paymentInfo.setTotalDue(request.getParameter("hiddenTotalDue"));

        int result = RentService.insertPaymentDB(paymentInfo);

        if(result > 0)
        {
            int vehicleID = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("id"));
            InventoryService.updateVehicleAvailabilty(vehicleID);
            response.sendRedirect("RentCar");
        }
        else
        {
            response.sendRedirect("failure.jsp");
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

why don't you put the value you take from either of the two forms in session like this

```
request.getsession.setAttribute("name", value);
```

then you can access it

```
String value=session.getAttribute("name").toString();
```

Comment: I was thinking about doing that but I was wondering if there was any other way of doing that

Comment: great, as it works fine you don't have to worry about any other ways